# Position of a point on a moving unit circle?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Suppose a unit circle is moving in a horizontal line at a speed given by $f(t)$ , and a point on the unit circle is moving counterclockwise at a speed given by $g(t)$ , and the initial position of the point is $0$ radians . and I want to find a function $s(t)$ in terms of $t$ for the position of the point on $[0, \infty)$ . This is my attempt:

$v_y=g(t) \,\sin t$

$v_x=g(t) \, \cos t+f(t)$

$v_{resultant}=[(g(t) \,\sin t)^2+(g(t) \, \cos t+f(t))^2]^{\frac 12}$

$s(t)= \int [(g(t) \,\sin t)^2+(g(t) \, \cos t+f(t))^2 ]^{\frac 12} dt$

Is this correct? Thanks.

Comment: You should use $(-\sin\theta(t), \cos\theta(t))$ for the direction of the tangent speed, where $1\cdot\dot{\theta}(t)=g(t)$

Comment: Is the circle rolling on the horizontal line ?

Comment: @TonyPiccolo no, it is "sliding"

Comment: Is the center of the circle at the origin or is the edge of the circle touching the x-axis? (I know you said it is sliding but this matters in terms of the solution).

Comment: @Jesse It is at the origin.

Comment: See **enzotib**'s comment and update $v_x$ and $v_y$ .